# Using jspdf library How to set a logo on a PDF through API

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I can get a png file through '**API**'.How can I include it in my PDF? , I'm using jsPDF and jsPDf-autoTable library too. I want the logo before (Header) the table and after (Footer) the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method

```
var img = new Image()
    img.src = '../../assets/arrow.png'
    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4")
    doc.addImage(img, 40, 30, 100, 76)
```